# A deleted testnet account gets fully restored

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm currently playing some stuffs with Near (**testnet**) following an example on github/Learn-NEAR/starter--near-sdk-as.

I accidentally deleted my account - quantransedev. After that I re-created with the same account name with new passphrase of course. I noticed the newly created account had everything the old one had. It seemed like a restore account.

Is this an expected behavior? it doesn't make sense to me at all in terms of security. Please advise.

https://explorer.testnet.near.org/accounts/quantransedev.testnet
https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/3GTFEzvTfDiAxm8fdpZeWP7NjRFTjFJaDYQNX6ANAUns

Comment: You should be contacting Near about this.

Comment: this is definitely the best way to ask about this, you're asking on Stackoverflow and you've tagged with `nearprotocol` so the whole team has visibility on your question

Comment: I'm surprised by the history of the first link and my guess is that you did not actually delete the account but set the same account as beneficiary so the delete action was ignored or something

Comment: You're right, I added the same account for CONTRACT and BENEFICIARY. Ref: https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/3GTFEzvTfDiAxm8fdpZeWP7NjRFTjFJaDYQNX6ANAUns.
Then I tried to access that account again and I cannot. The saved passphrases didn't work.
Finally I created an account with the same name (I guess anybody else could do that), with new passphrases, and now I got the account back. Just wonder this can lead to any security hole or something.

Comment: @amgando this is only for tagging.

Comment: all good -- for sure if you delete an account, anyone else can create the same account.  no surprise there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account had been deleted and the remaining funds were burnt since the beneficiary account did not exist (the account got removed before the transfer was initiated). You can also confirm that the account had actually been removed by reviewing the next transactions (deletion of other accounts with beneficiary account id set to `quantransedev.testnet`) did not succeed to transfer the remaining tokens from the removed accounts (the tokens got burnt).

You had had to re-create the account explicitly from scratch: https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/CroKF7ipwM3fDgH5ogVrnWS6JSmnhvjkaJNDqiWzjsm2 to gain control over the account id. Before that moment, the account did not exist on the chain. Explorer, however, keeps track of all the ever-existing accounts on the network, which might have confused you.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior - when you delete an account it does not delete all the things this account owns or controls. That needs to be done manually before account is deleted.

Account deletion just deletes the information about this specific account state on-chain.

When you recreate the account - it will actually be back to controlling whatever was linking to it by account id.

Generally, if you delete account - that name and things it owns are up for grubs for anyone else, so account deletion should be done very careful.

Filed two issues to improve experience here:

- https://github.com/near/nearcore/issues/5816
- https://github.com/near/near-cli/issues/900